# Accessing network data from the OS kernel using C#

Tags: c#, operating-system

I am trying to create a prot scanner that will scan only the host system. Initially, I had done this by attempting to make connections to ports to determine if they are open. Whilst this works, it takes quite a while. Instead I was wondering if there is a way to access this information straight from the OS or a similar way to the Listening Ports section in the Resource Monitor. Any pointers or tips would be great.
Thanks

Comment: IMHO, I think you need something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10054653/how-can-i-learn-about-the-win32-api

Comment: Thanks, I'll start looking there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IpHlpApi.dll` should contain WinAPI functions you need, here is wrapper and sample:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box

Comment: Thanks, this is a massive help!